# Benefits between .ToList().First() verse .Single for IQueryable in c#

Tags: c#, linq, nosql

So I am running a linq query on a NOSQL database that should return only a single object if one exists with that Id or nothing if nothing exists, but it is possible there are two objects with the same id in the database (if someone else messed up.) Currently I have it implemented as follows:

```
(from c in [IQueryableThing] where c.Id.Equals(id)).ToList().First()
```

I have also considered the alternative

```
(from c in [IQueryableThing] where c.Id.Equals(id)).Single()
```

I assume .Single() is faster but I am concerned that neither of these handles the case that there is no object with the correct id in the database. I don't care if there is more than one returned. I only want one of them. Eventually I will implement something to return the most recently modified.

Basically my question is what is the best way to solve this problem of converting a queryable to a single instance in a way that handles the cases where there is no object with the correct id and there is more than one object with the correct id.

Comment: **How** do you want it to handle that?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It sounds like you just want to call `FirstOrDefault()`, which does exactly what the name implies.
`Default` means `null`.

You should not call `ToList()`; that will needlessly download all of the results from the database.

Comment: Agreed, most of the time seems to be the safest option.

Comment: So ToList() requires extra calculation?

Comment: @inquisitiveIdiot not nessesaraly extra calculation but extra data transfered between the server and your client. If you have a database that has 10 million rows and you do `ToList().First()` 10 milion rows must be transmitted to your application and then your application just reads the first row and your application never uses the other 9,999,999 rows. If you do `FirstOrDefault()` only 1 row gets transmitted and your application uses that 1 row.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain it is NoSQL so document based and more specifically mongoDB so does that matter?

Comment: It all depends on if `IQueryableThing` is using [Linq2Entites](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386964.aspx) or [Linq2Objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397919.aspx) under the hood. If entities, it will make a big diffrence, if objects, it will still make a difference (you still are copying 10 million objects in memory to a List then throwing all but one away) but not as much.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain how can i tell? I use the toList operation a lot for this type of application

Comment: @inquisitiveIdiot: You should only call `ToList()` if you actually want to download the entire result over the network and save it in memory.

Comment: @SLaks Ok so only use ToList() when I actually need to be able to use the object as a list later. Thank you for your help\

Comment: @SLaks Default means null in this context as its a Reference type.  That's not the case if it were a Value type, right?

Comment: @Harrison: Yes.  However, DB entities should not be value types.

Answer (score 5):

Using `IQueryable.Single` is more efficient:

- Calling `ToList` enumerates the entire result set and stores each item in an single, contiguous array in memory. The `First` then just takes the first item from the array.
- Calling `IQueryable.Single` evaluates only the first item in the list, and if no items are returned, throws an exception. It then checks to see if there are any more items in the result set, and throws an exception if there are any.

If you'd like to handle the case where no items exist in the set which match your criteria, but don't care if there are more than one, I'd **strongly** recommend using [`FirstOrDefault`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340482.aspx) instead:

```
var result = (from c in [IQueryableThing] where c.Id.Equals(id)).FirstOrDefault();
if (result == null)
{
    // no items found
}
```

This will translate to a `TOP 1` in SQL, and simply return the first item in the result set, or if the result set is empty, it will simply return `null` (or the default value if you're dealing with structs).

Answer (score 3):

The `.ToList()` shouldn't make a difference, it will just enumerate the queryable into an in-memory list.  For your situation, you have a number of options.  The two you've shown behave very differently:

- `.First()` - This will return the first element in the enumeration, or throw an exception if there are none.
- `.Single()` - This will return the *only* element in the enumeration, or throw an exception if there are none *or* if there are more than one.
- `.FirstOrDefault()` - This will return the first element in the enumeration, or a default value (which is `null` for reference types) if there are none.
- `.SingleOrDefault()` - This will return the *only* element in the enumeration, or a default value (which is `null` for reference types) if there are none, *or* throw an exception if there are more than one.

It sounds like you want to use `.FirstOrDefault()`.  Check if the result is `null`.  If it is, there were no matching elements.  If it isn't, you have the first matching element.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are looking for [`Enumerable.FirstOrDefault`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340482.aspx)

> Returns the first element of a sequence, or a default value if the
>   sequence contains no elements.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `.FirstOrDefault(c => c.ID.Equals(id));`

It will return default if nothing is found (default is `null` for classes) or the first one it finds.

Answer (score 0):

In case you are sure that ONE and only ONE item exists and you will want to use Single()

If case you are not sure how many items will be returned used First() Or FirstOrDefault().

The difference is that Single() will throw an exception if more than one item exists. Very usefull if you want to trap insertion errors etc on a database without unique constraints.